# Solaar and piper not detecting my old Logitech MX Revolution 5500

Tags: mouse, logitech

Hello I have researched and found Solaar and piper are the best softwares for customising
Logitech mouse buttons applications. But the only problem is that they (Solaar and piper) are not detecting my MX Revolution.
How do I fix this?
Thanks in advance.
My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Focal Fossa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Ubuntu does not support my specific mouse's software. So it is not possible to edit a Logitech MX Revolution mouse settings on any Linux distro. You can do it on Windows.